# Що таке капернаум, капернаумчик?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

У "Недузі" Плужника:

> — А **капернаумчик**-то невеселий попався нам, — промовив Куниця, обдивляючись навкруги.

Контекст: два товариші заходять в одну пивницю, і один іншому таке каже.

Ось є таке [колишнє місто в Ізраїлі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC) від:

כְּפַר נַחוּם‎ (кфар нахум) — «село Наума» або **«село розради»**.

Але жодної згадки про фразеолоґічне вживання такого слова я поки не знайшов.

На r2u є ще дві [згадки](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on). Одна з них біблійна. З іншої також незрозуміло, що значить це слово.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Підтверджую версію користувача Yola.
Знайшов дипломну роботу "[Формирование туристической программы для гостей Санкт-Петербурга](https://wudger.ru/cg/menedzhment-organizacii/formirovanie-turisticheskoj-programmy-gostej-sankt-peterburga.htm)", де пише:

> "Трактир Давидова називали "Капернаумом". Шевченко Т.Г. запевняв, що
>   цю назву придумав в майбутньому відомий скульптор С.С. Піменов для
>   трактиру "Берлін" на 6-ій лінії Василівського острову [46;71]. З
>   легкої руки Піменова "капернаумами" жартівливо почали називати майже
>   всі схожі заклади Петербурга. Хоч, здається, що "капернаумами"
>   називали трактири не лише в столиці, але й по всій Русі. Фет А. А.
>   згадував про знайомого свого батька старого М., який регулярно
>   запрошував його "заглянути в "Капернаумчик", маючи на увазі найближчий
>   трактир.[43;201]

Бачимо, що у роботі подаються посилання. Перше джерело:

**Шевченко Т.Г. // Повне зiбрания творiв: у 12 т. Т. 4.: Повiстi. Кiев, 2003. С. 126.**

Мені вдалося відшукати джерело на [Порталі Шевченка](http://kobzar.ua/item/show/238). І там на сторінці **125** пише (цитую Шевченка без перекладу, так як користувач Yola вже переклав його слова):

> Поправил ему контур, проложил тени, и мы отправились в «Капернаум» чай
>   пить. «Капернаум»  — сиречь  трактир  «Берлин»  на  углу  Шестой линии
>   и  Академического переулка.  Так окрестил  его, кажется, Пименов во
>   время своего удалого студенчества.

Друге джерело:

**Фет А. Воспоминания / Предисл. Д. Благого. Сост. и прим. А. Тархова.М.: Правда, 1983. – 239 с.**

Знайшов його в [Гугл книгах](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=2tWhDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA375&lpg=PA375&dq=%D0%A4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%90.%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=Cp-6twMvzA&sig=ACfU3U39qNkBQNlhMHvC2SU3jMp0IAVvIw&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitrpvvqr7hAhVuxosKHVVxCA4Q6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%A4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%90.%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA&f=false), де пише:

> "А чи не заглянути нам в "Капернаумчик?" - він же вказав мені і
>   іллюмінацію слободи, якою сам кожну ніч захоплювався. А стосовно
>   трактиру, куди водив мене М., то це був досить хороший російський
>   **трактир**...

Тако натрапив на російську статтю "[Капернаум (трактир)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC_(%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80))" на Вікіпедії:

> Трактир «Капернаум» — одне з улюблених місць зустрічей серед
>   літераторів, які відігравали роль своєрідних суспільно-політичних
>   клубів характерних для петербурзької культури кінця XIX — початку XX
>   століть.

В самій же статті є і пояснення (слово справді пов'язане з містом Капернаум) і стаття посилається на різні джерела.

Стаття пояснює, що назва походить від міста [Капернаум](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC) (або ж Кафарнаум чи Кфар Нахум - від івр.  כְּפַר נַחוּם - "село розради", [נִחוּם](https://www.morfix.co.il/%D7%A0%D6%B7%D7%97%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9D) - "розрада"), яке зустрічається в Новому Завіті. В Російській імперії це слово стало популярним і ним почали називати трактири, де люди могли не лише поїсти, а ще й поговорити на різні теми.

Answer (score 4):

У своїй автобіографічній повісті *Художник* Шевченко [пише](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE)):

> Я полагодив йому нарис, провів сутїнї і ми пішли до „**Капернаума**“ чай
>   пити. „**Капернаум**“ — се просто ресторан „Берлин“, на розї шестої
>   „лїнїї“ і академічного переулка: **Капернаумом** охрестив його, здаєть ся,
>   Піменов підчас свого голїнного студенства.

Після цього в Петербурзі жартома так називали всі ресторани. А товариші зайшли в пивницю, яку один з них і назвав так.

Comment: Ага... це цікава версія, насправді. Я почекаю ще відповідей. Хотілось би додаткових свідчень.